# Microsoft STL: Constant values always on the left in conditionals?

Tags: c++, stl, coding-style

I've noticed that most conditionals in Microsoft STL `<algorithm>` (at least VS2012 version) are written using only the < operator, often leaving the constants on the left-hand side of the expressions:

```
if (40 < _Last - _First)
...
for (_Diff _Hole = _Bottom / 2; 0 < _Hole; )
...
for (; 1 < _Last - _First; --_Last)
...
for (; _ISORT_MAX < (_Count = _Last - _First) && 0 < _Ideal; )
...
```

This might be sometimes [arguably] counterintuitive and difficult to comprehend, so I suspect there is a reason for that.

However, in comparison, [Libc++](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/algorithm) does not seem to use this style and employ both
ways to compare integral values:

```
if (__len >= __alloc_limit)
...
for (_D1 __loop_unroll = (__s - __first1) / 4; __loop_unroll > 0; --__loop_unroll)
...
```

So I believe this is not performance-related.

What is the logic behind this? Is it just code style related (and if it is, why?),
or maybe some other hint for compiler?

Comment: Possibly an extension of the sensible (and life saving) rule to put constant on the left when using `==` so that the compiler would yell if you accidentally wrote `=`.

Comment: @Leeor Except that all sane compilers yell at an unparenthesised `=` in conditionals anyway.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a law, but a [Standard Library guideline](http://isocpp.org/std/library-design-guidelines) is

> generic code should only assume == and < out of their respective group

Furthermore, there is a readability bonus for comparisons that read left-to-right because this is how most people are used to ordering numbers. Compare

```
a <= b && b < c
```

vs

```
b >= a && c > b
```

The first version makes it immediately clear that `b` is in the range `[a, c)`, whereas the second version is much harder to parse for a human. Since the Standard Library uses ranges extensively, it is probably easier for their maintainers to write assertions and other code in the left-to-right style.

Answer (score 2):

Many algorithms and containers (as for example associative containers) require that there will be defined operator < (that usually sets weak ordering). It can not be substituted for  for example operator >= because classes are not required to define it and it would be difficult to write general algorithms. The only requirement that there will be operator <.

As for this example

```
if (__len >= __alloc_limit)
```

then as I understand __len and __alloc_limit are fundamental types for which operator >= is already defined. That is a user need not to define this operator. It already exists. So there is no problem which operator to select for using. You can use any relational operator.

Comment: Vlad, this is true for comparison user data types, and in the STL code you will always see the _DEBUG_LT() macro when it's comparing container elements, for example. However, I'm talking about integral comparisons that are independent of the template type.

Comment: I think that the rule of using operator < for algorithms and containers makes it as a good programming practice or style to keep this rule for fundamental types.

Answer (score 1):

It's a habit a lot of developers get into. The reason for it is that in C/C++ you can write something like this:

```
if (i=1) doSomething();
```

Where you meant to compare `i` to 1, but ended up assiging 1 to `i` instead (because you missed the extra `=` off), thus the `if` statement will always be true.

By placing the constant on the left hand side, like this:

```
if (1=i) doSomething();
```

You'll get a compile error in this case which is vastly better than before where the code compiled but had a bug in it.

Because of this a lot of developers stick to the policy that if you're doing any sort of comparison with a literal you put it on the left/

Comment: "If seven equals my counter then...": this is awkward to read and provides false sense of security. IMO it's still better to try and learn to recognize the language's regular traps. The sooner you learn that in C++ `=` means assignment, the better.

Comment: @NonNumeric - I agree, I also find it awkward. The problem in C/C++ is that int types decay to booleans. In languages like Java and C# it's not an issue as `if(i=1)` would give you a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

It's to prevent accidental bugs. E.g.

```
if(x = 10)   // But you meant x == 10
{
}
```

compiles, but can be a nasty bug because it looks ok at a glance.

However,

```
if(10 = x)
{
}
```

is a compiler error, so you know immediately to change it to `if(10 == x)`.